# How do I enable/disable apache httpd based upon my laptop's network location?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, apache-http-server, automation

I have a laptop that I use for consulting and that travels with me from client to client.  I use httpd to code/test on my machine at home and bind it to the global address in order to test functionality on other devices (iPad, Android, et al).

I don't want my ip escaping when I connect my laptop to other networks and have thusfar diligently been shutting down apache when I leave my personal network however I'd like a degree of automation in order to be able to declare:

```
stop service httpd
when
network location <> 'X'
```

or even:

```
firewall service httpd
when
network location <> 'X'
```

I've spotted [control plane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) and will dig into it farther, but it looks like it might not work on OS X 10.9.

Is anyone doing this:

1. More generally with apache and network controls?
2. More specifically on OS X?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself but it sounded uncomplicated to script so here's a one-liner to build upon:

```
if [[ `ifconfig \-u \`networksetup -listallhardwareports|grep Wi-Fi -A 1|grep Device|awk '{print $2}'\` inet|grep inet|awk '{print $2}'` = 192.168.1.100 ]];then apachectl start; else apachectl graceful-stop;fi
```

Breaking this down:

- I used *`networksetup -listallhardwareports|grep Wi-Fi -A 1|awk '{print $2}'`* to figure out the device identifier. In my case it was en0.
- I encased this in backtics so that it would be piped into *`ifconfig -u (en0) inet`*.  The *`-u`* searches for adapters that are active or UP and *`inet`* returned IPv4 info. You can change this to *`inet6`* to change the query to IPv6.
- I wrapped this an *`if [[ ]]`* test and compared the value to the IP address I want it to allow enablement on and stop if the match fails.

You'll just have to decide how you want to kick this off.  Perhaps a logon script or possibly a launch script to run at will.  HTH.